# CMake regex match

Tags: regex, cmake

I have a CMake string variable:

```
set(var "String0 String_1 String_2")
```

I need to select whatever is before the first whitespace from this variable (`"String0"`) and make a new variable with this content.

I used CMake's `REGEX MATCH` method to do this and used this regex: `'\S\w*'`. I have tested that regex on an online regex interpreter and it worked.

I have written this code in CMake (after setting the variable of course):

```
string(REGEX MATCH "\S\w*" NEW_VAR "${VAR}")
```

When I do this the script complains about invalid skipping of characters (`S` and `w`). So, next, I tried escaping both the slashes:

```
string(REGEX MATCH "\\S\\w*" NEW_VAR "${VAR}")
```

Now `NEW_VAR` equal `'S'` instead of `"String0"` as I was expecting.

Please help me correct this, since I have very little experience with regular expressions and CMake.

Comment: CMake has its **own** [regex specification](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/string.html#regex-specification), and this specification lacks of character classes like `\S` and `\w`.

Comment: thank you. I have found a regex that works. Not sure holw good it is for all cases but from what I've tested seems to work

Comment: On Stack Overflow we tend to NOT answer on the question in the question post itself. Instead, you are allowed to [answer on your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Please, move your last `Edit` paragrapgh into the answer post.

Comment: done. sorry it took 2 weeks

Answer (score 3):

You could also search for the location of the first occurrence of a whitespace character and select the [substring](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#substring) from the start of this string till that position:

```
set(var "String_0 String_1 String_2")

string(FIND ${var} " " wsloc)
message(STATUS "position of first whitespace character: ${wsloc}")

string(SUBSTRING ${var} 0 ${wsloc} newvar)
message(STATUS "selected substring: \"${newvar}\"")
```

Comment: thanks but I was looking for smth smaller like a line of code no more :D

Comment: @Kennedy not stated in the question, but no worries. This is just 2 lines and uses no regex, so there might be some merit there; not sure what strings you're coming up against.

Comment: it worked for some examples i've tried in the interpreter. should be ok thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I have used this and it works(not sure how good it is for all cases, though):

```
.[(A-z)|(a-z)|(0-9)]*
```

Comment: You are almost certainly mixing two different regex features here. The stuff between `[` and `]` is simply an enumeration of characters, with no other special facilities than character ranges and negation. You are including `(` and `)` and `|` in the character class (multiple times), probably needlessly.

Comment: As tripleee says, you would use `.[A-Za-z0-9]*`